# If $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i$ converges, does $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \arcsin(a_i)$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

If $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i$ converges, does $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \arcsin(a_i)$ converge? If not, give a counterexample.

Comment: What have are your ideas?

Comment: I actually believe it's false but I can't come up with a counterexample

Comment: Do you mean $\sum a_i$? Because $\sum a$ converges only when $a=0$....

Comment: Yes ∑ai. I'm trying to figure out if given a convergent series ∑ai, will ∑arcsin(ai) converge as well is a true statement

Answer (score 6):

Note that $\arcsin(2x)-2\arcsin(x)>0$ for $x>0$.
Now we can easily produce a converging $\sum a_i$ with the property that $a_{3k-1}=a_{3k-2}=-\frac12a_{3k}$ for all $k$ ; in fact it suffices to ensure $a_{3k}\to 0$ to have convergence of the series.
At the same time $\arcsin a_{3k-2}+\arcsin a_{3k-1}+\arcsin a_{3k}$ can be strictly positive and we can repeat the same triple / the same positive contribution, until these repeated triples contribute at least $\frac 1n$, say, to the arcsine sum. Then the arcsine series compares to the harmonic series and diverges.

---

More generally, we have

**Proposition.** Assume $f\colon D\to \Bbb R$ is a function defined in a neighbourhood of $0$ and such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $x,y,z\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cap D$ and $x+y+z=0$ and $f(x)+f(y)+f(z)\ne 0$.
Then there exists $(a_i)_{i\in \Bbb N}$ with $a_i\in D$ for all $i$ and $\sum a_i=0$ and $\sum f(a_i)$ diverges.

*Proof.*
For $m\in\Bbb N$ pick $x_m,y_m,z_m\in(-\frac1m,\frac1m)\cap D$ with $x_m+y_m+z_m=0$ and $f(x_m)+f(y_m)+f(z_m)\ne 0$. Wlog. $f(x_m)+f(y_m)+f(z_m)> 0$ for infinitely many $m$. Hence wlog. $f(x_m)+f(y_m)+f(z_m)> 0$  for all $m$.
Let $r_m=\lceil\frac1{f(x_m)+f(y_m)+f(z_m)}\rceil$ and $s_m=r_1+\ldots+r_m$.
Then for $n\in \Bbb N$, $n=3k-t$, $t\in\{0,1,2\}$ let $$\tag1a_n=\begin{cases}x_m&\text{if }t=0\\y_m&\text{if }t=1\\z_m&\text{if }t=2\end{cases}\quad\text{where $m$ is minimal with $s_m\ge k$}.$$
Then the $n$th partial sum does not exceed $\frac 1m$ in absolute value (with $m$ as defined in $(1)$), hence $\sum a_i$ converges to $0$.
On the other hand, 
$$\sum_{i=3s_m-2}^{3s_{m+1}-3}f(a_i) =r_m\cdot(f(x_m)+f(y_m)+f(z_m))\ge 1$$
so that $\sum_{i=3s_1-2}^{3s_{m+1}-3}f(a_i)\ge m$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}f(a_i)$ diverges. $_\square$

*Remark:* For continuous $f$, the condition of the proposition is already given if there is no neighbourhood of $0$ on which $f$ is linear. In particular, the condition holds for $f(x)=\arcsin x$.

Comment: Which convergent series are you using as a counterexample?

Comment: @kimLee For example, I can repeat $-\frac12,-\frac12,1,-\frac12,-\frac12,1,-\frac12,-\frac12,1,\ldots$ until the arcsine sum exceed $1$. Then continue with $-\frac14,-\frac14,\frac12,-\frac14,-\frac14,\frac12,\ldots$ until the arsine sum exceed $2$, and so on.

Comment: No, something more specific like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/n^2. Something with closed form.

Comment: @kimLee What's unspecific?

Comment: I'd like to see a convergent series with closed form.

Comment: You can show that $\arcsin(2x)-2\arcsin(x)=\alpha x^3 +o(x^4)$ for some non-zero constant $\alpha$. Then choose $a_{3k-2}=a_{3k-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\;\sum_i a_i$ converges absolutely, $\;\arcsin a_i$ converges absolutely.

Indeed, $a_i$ tends to $0\;$ and $\;a_i\sim \arcsin a_i$. Two series with equivalent terms both converge absolutely or both diverge absolutely.

Comment: Is there a more formal proof to this using a convergence test?

Comment: You can use this: $\lvert \arcsin x\rvert\le\dfrac{\pi\lvert x\rvert}2$ for any $x\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: What is informal about appealing to a known theorem? @kimLee

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Maybe the O.P. didn't have a class on asymptotic analysis.

Comment: @Bernard are you saying your statement is true? what is the reasoning behind it?

Comment: Do you mean, in my answer?

Comment: This answer is about *absolute* convergence.

Comment: Bernard is saying that if you have a stronger condition - that $\sum|a_i|$ converges (called absolute convergence) then you can conclude that $\sum \arcsin a_i$ converges. @kimLee

Comment: Why does arcsin not change the convergence? @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Because when $x$ is small, $\arcsin x$ is closer and closer to $x$.